# I am looking for a function that maps an integer X to 0.X without using a loop

Tags: python, algorithm, math, mapping

I am trying to come up with a function that maps an integer X to the decimal 0.X without using a loop.

Examples:

- 4 -> 0.4
- 65 -> 0.65
- 1584 -> 0.1584

I figured I could do something like this:

```
def mapToDec(x):
  while x > 1:
    x = x / 10
  return x
```

However, I am looking for something more sophisticated that doesn't require a loop, something that would look like a mathematical function perhaps.

Comment: What language is this?  Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @alexandrosangeli The question doesn't mention what the purpose is, but it may be worth noting that such a function will not necessarily be invertible, in the sense that you won't (always) be able to recover the original integer from the floating point value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have shown that there is such a function by implementing one.  If you want one without a loop, how about

```
def mapToDec(x):
    return x * 10 ** -(1 + math.floor(math.log10(x)))
```

Comment: `x / 10 ** (1 + math.floor(math.log10(x)))` seems to work with better precision

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for.